# az acr login results in error: can’t find token from MSAL cache

Tags: azure, azure-cli

Installed podman on MacBook Pro m1. When I run:

```
Token=#(az acr login —name myname —expose-token —output tsv query access Token)
```

I get the following error:

```
ERROR: can’t find token from MSAL cache. 
To re-authetnicate, please run  az login
```

I logged in after running `az login` and authenticated, but still have the same error.

Comment: Refer to https://github.com/Azure/azure-cli/issues/4618#issuecomment-839650116 and

Answer (score 1):

- Try clearing the cache from the `.azure` folder from the home directory `/var/root`
- Also clear the cache using [MSAL.net](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/msal-net-clear-token-cache)

> Clearing the cache is achieved by removing the accounts from the cache. This does not remove the session cookie which is in the browser, though.

- Now re check the installation of [Podman](https://podman.io/getting-started/installation) once again.

Answer (score 1):

**tl;dr : check the system time.**

I received the same error with Azure command line although I was logged in according to the web browser :

> Can't find token from MSAL cache.
>
> To re-authenticate, please run:
>
> az login

There was a traceback in the terminal from which I launched `az login`, with the following message :

> 0. The ID token is not yet valid. Current epoch = 1650445935.

Turned out the VM system time was wrong, and I could access my blobs after setting it correctly.